# Epson Workforce 845 all in scanner one does not come up under Linux or Win10

Tags: linux, scanner, epson-workforce

Apologies if this is the wrong forum. I’ve spent over twelve hours scrubbing the internet for something that works. Ideas on better forums will also be appreciated.

12-28 edit at bottom showing nmap results.
12-29 edit at bottom showing wireshark traces

**The Problem**
While my Epson Workforce 845 all in one printer comes up just fine with network access on Win10 and Linux the networked scanner has been resisting coming up on Windows 10 and Linux. While this scanner was fully working on now decommissioned versions of Windows and Linux how to bring it up on W10 and Linux is a popular topic for unsolved solutions, at least for me. I’ve given up on Win10 leaving Linux as my target solution.

The Lubuntu I'm attempting now is running within Virtual Box and gets this pop up:

```
       iscan
Could not send command to scanner. 
Check scanner status.
```

The following logs to syslog for each failure:

```
v-lubuntu-1804 iscan: io/hpmud/model.c 543: no on_workforce_845 attributes found in /usr/share/hplip/data/models/unreleased/unreleased.dat
```

Note the "hplip" HP directory in the logged path for an Epson scanner. There is no HP scanner on the network.

**System Basics**
    Linux v-lubuntu-1804 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gzs
    VirtualBox Version 6.0.0 r127566 (Qt5.6.2).
       Using "bridged" network adapter.
    WV844 firmware: CR04G3 6B.6B

Network, not USB, connection on all in one.

The table the windows/Lubuntu system sits on has it’s own router with a LAN port hard wired to a LAN port of the main router with the table’s router WAN port being empty and DNS/gateway settings pointing to the main router and DHCP off.  This has worked years without trouble. The scanner is hardwired to the main router and not the local table’s router. Thus the scanner is only accessible by network.

Though this is an Epson scanner, and I have "#" commented out the hplio line within dll.d/hplip, then entirely deleted the file, using iscan still syslogs with the hplip directory. Further there is no workforce_845 string anywhere within the sane.d directory tree:

```
/etc/sane.d$ grep -r workforce_845 .  

iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb$ ls plugins
iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb

ping p-epsonwf845
PING p-epsonwf845.fios-router.home (192.168.8.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from p-epsonwf845.fios-router.home (192.168.8.200): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=9.34 ms

# package status
$ dpkg-query --list '*epson*' '*sane*' '*scan*'
||/ Name            Version      Architecture Description
+++-===============-============-============-===================================
ii  epson-inkjet-p 1.0.0-1lsb3. amd64        Epson Inkjet Printer Driver - Wor
ii  iscan          2.30.1-1~usb amd64        simple, easy to use scanner utili
ii  iscan-data     1.36.0-1     all          Image Scan! for Linux data files
ii  iscan-network- 1.1.1-1      amd64        Image Scan! Network Plugin
un  iscan-plugin-c <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  iscan-plugin-g <none>       <none>       (no description available)
    . . .
un  libsane        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libsane-common 1.0.27-1~exp all          API library for scanners -- docum
un  libsane-extras <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libsane-hpaio: 3.17.10+repa amd64        HP SANE backend for multi-functio
ii  libsane1:amd64 1.0.27-1~exp amd64        API library for scanners
un  mediascanner2. <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  sane-utils     1.0.27-1~exp amd64        API library for scanners -- utili
```

**Alternate Install**
Also installed xsane for comparison but that could not find any devices when it was started.

**Configuration Files**
The configuration files are currently sitting at:

```
# dll.conf - Configuration file for the SANE dynamic backend loader
net
epkowa

# epkowa.conf -- sample configuration for the EPKOWA SANE backend
#net scanner.mydomain.com
net 192.168.8.200

# dll.d/hplip
#: hpaio

# dll.d/iscan -- enables the SANE backend(s) required
# Any changes to this file will be lost when upgrading iscan.
epkowa
```

**12-28 Edit**

Note the nmap did not show the SANE ports 1865 (sane) nor 5353 (unknown to me) mentioned by ljm, but strace does not show 9100 from the following nmap.

```
$ nmap 192.168.8.200
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-12-28 22:33 EST
Nmap scan report for p-epsonwf845.fios-router.home (192.168.8.200)
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
515/tcp  open  printer
631/tcp  open  ipp
9100/tcp open  jetdirect

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.38 seconds
```

Pointing a web browser at the printer pulls a a printer configuration page without mentioning a scanner. Is there a special URL for the scanner?

**12-29 Edit**

Interesting packets from Wireshark just stop after MDNS seem to have failed despite the fact one did hit the scanner.

```
No. Time          Source         SP   Destination DP   Proto Mac_src           Mac_dst
 2  0.990762954   192.168.8.181 5353 224.0.0.251 5353 MDNS  PcsCompu_58:18:14 IPv4mcast_fb
 6  1.101184820   192.168.8.200 5353 224.0.0.251 5353 MDNS  SeikoEps_bb:a5:c4 IPv4mcast_fb
0000:   0000 0000  0100 5e00  00fb 0026  abbb a5c4    /......^....&..../
0010:   0800 4500  0000 0010  0143 0000  4000 ff11    /..E......C..@.../
0020:   843d c0a8  54c8 e000  0000 0020  00fb 14e9    /.=..T...... ..../
0030:   14e9 012f  9ff5 0000  8400 0000  0000 0030    /.../...........0/
0040:   0001 0000  0003 085f  7363 616e  6e65 7204    /......._scanner./
0050:   0000 0040  5f74 6370  056c 6f63  616c 0000    /...@_tcp.local../
0060:   0c00 0100  0000 0050  0011 9400  1613 4550    /.......P......EP/
0070:   534f 4e20  576f 726b  0000 0060  466f 7263    /SON Work...`Forc/
0080:   6520 3834  35c0 0c0b  4550 534f  0000 0070    /e 845...EPSO...p/
0090:   4e42 4241  3543 34c0  1a00 0180  0100 0000    /NBBA5C4........./
00a0:   0000 0080  7800 04c0  a854 c8c0  2b00 2180    /....x....T..+.!./
00b0:   0100 0000  0000 0090  7800 0800  0000 0007    /........x......./
00c0:   49c0 41c0  2b00 1080  0000 00a0  0100 0011    /I.A.+.........../
00d0:   9400 aa09  7478 7476  6572 733d  0000 00b0    /....txtvers=..../
00e0:   3116 7479  3d45 5053  4f4e 2057  6f72 6b46    /1.ty=EPSON WorkF/
00f0:   0000 00c0  6f72 6365  2038 3435  3a61 646d    /....orce 845:adm/
0100:   696e 7572  0000 00d0  6c3d 6874  7470 3a2f    /inur....l=http://
0110:   2f45 5053  4f4e 4242  0000 00e0  4135 4334    //EPSONBB....A5C4/
 8  2.053039044   192.168.8.181 5353 224.0.0.251 5353 MDNS  PcsCompu_58:18:14 IPv4mcast_fb
```

Comment: You may need to make yourself a member of the scanner group.

Comment: Search did not turn up "scanner". What is real name.

Comment: See if this helps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo (specifically permission issues section, but the rest may also be useful).

Comment: BTW `getent group` will list every group so you can see if it exists.

Comment: Thanks but seen most of that. Running as root makes no difference. As I understand scand is for allowing other computers to connect to scanners the local host can access; this is not the case here as the scanner is parked on a router as a pure network device. This makes the group permissions not that relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On our Windows systems loading the latest Epson scanner-only driver update over the latest Epson printer/scanner bundle allows the scanner to work.

Answer (score 0):

So you have Iscan up and running; it just fails to access the scanner.

Make sure that in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`, you have enabled:

- `net`
- `epkowa`

You might need to disable the other Epson back-ends.

In `epkowa.conf`, you will need:

```
usb
scsi
net 192.168.8.200
```

You might want to disable `net autodiscovery`.

Comment: Already did that -- it seems my configuration file extracts were lost in a prior edit. Added them back thanks to  your comment making me look.

Comment: What does `scanimage -L` say?

Comment: No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).

Comment: Running strace I observe it hits the scanner:   1226  08:37:02 recvfrom(8, "\0\0\204\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\3\10_scanner\4_tcp\5local"..., 2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5353), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.84.200")}, [16]) = 295

Comment: hm. Port 5353; normally sane thinks it is port 1865 for epkowa. Can you do an `nmap` on the printer to see which ports are open there?

Comment: nmap 192.168.84.200 produces 80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
515/tcp  open  printer
631/tcp  open  ipp
9100/tcp open  jetdirect

Comment: You should normally get a page where you can choose some network settings, firmware update and printer-info. I have not seen any scanner info on the web page for the Epson's I've seen (which are admittedly few). Is it an option for you to deinstall all drivers and start with the `utsushi`drivers?

Comment: Noticed somewhere out on the greater internet a comment about scanning from Epson scanners using the http interface. My mind may be wrong in the brand, through it sent me to the web interface to test it out. My biggest use of this interface is to hit it with curl to verify it is properly oneline.

Comment: Can revert the VM and try utsushi.  Is there a Lubuntu/Ubuntu friendly package download area? github seems obsolete and gitlab norpool/utsushi and utsushi/utsushi are showing "An error occurred while loading commit signatures" and I can't read the README files therein as it sticks with the spinning dots.. Anyway I would prefer a package built by someone that knows the project rather than doing it myself.

Comment: Updated with Wireshark trace

Comment: Looked into 5353, that is probably Apple bonjour, so don't set your hopes on that. Perhaps it is possible to find a pre-packaged version (I couldn't find one), but I would however recommend building from source, https://gitlab.com/utsushi/utsushi/